# Was trying to implement a pause decorator for my app but i have issues following another question

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I have a service file:

```
export class MockDataService {
   data:[] = [];

   getAll(): Observable<any[]> { return of(this.data); }
}
```

I wanted to essentially create a delay for my mocks, so i wanted to wrap a `@pause()` decorator around all the functions:

```
export async function pause() {
    await new Promise( res => setTimeout(res, 1500) );
}
```

So essentially, all endpoints will have a 1.5 second pause.  I add it to getAll:

```
@pause()
getAll() {}
```

but it gives me an error from my intellisense. `Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
  Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Promise<void>' has no compatible call signatures.`

I was trying to figure out how I would accomplish this.  Are my function signatures wrong?  I will eventually be leveraging Http calls in the functions, so I thought I had the correct function defi

Comment: What happens if you make the pause function return type to  `any` ?

Comment: @callback instead of it not being defined?  Pause will say: ```The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type.```

Comment: What happens when you serve with the following params `--target ES5 --emitDecoratorMetadata --experimentalDecorators` ? (assuming youre using the cli)

Comment: Those commands are not valid for *ng serve*

Comment: @callback It gives the errors: 'unknown option '--target', etc for each of your params.

Comment: How about adding `"target": "ES5"` in the tsconfig.json, under `compilerOptions`

Comment: I already had those flags set in the tsconfig.json file.  Target was es2015, not es5, but everything else was already in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because Method decorator must have the following signature:

```
declare type MethodDecorator = <T>(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>) => TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> | void;
```

It can't return `Promise<void>`. It must return `TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>` or must be void. Since you are dealing with `Observable<>` you need to use `delay` operator from `rxjs/operators`:

```
export function observablePause(
  target: Object,
  propertyName: string,
  propertyDesciptor: PropertyDescriptor): PropertyDescriptor {
  const method = propertyDesciptor.value;

  propertyDesciptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {

      // invoke decorated method and get its return value
      let result = <Observable<any>>method.apply(this, args);
      // adding delay
      result = result.pipe(delay(1500));
      // return the result of invoking the method
      return result;
  }
  return propertyDesciptor;
};
...
@observablePause
getAll(): Observable<any[]> { return of(this.data); }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you your wait, but I think you might have additional issues with the observable response.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MockDataService {

  data: [] = [];

  @delay()
  downloadData() {
    return this.data;
  }

  getAll(): Observable<any[]> {
    return of(this.downloadData());
  }

  constructor() {
  }
}

export function delay(): MethodDecorator {
  return function(target: Function, key: string, descriptor: any) {

    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value =  async function(...args: any[]) {
      console.log('Entering Wait!');
      await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1500));
      console.log('Completed Wait!');
      return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    };

    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

Comment: By decorating non-async function with async function you are changing method signature from `() => Observable<any[]>` to `() => Promise<Observable<any[]>>` at runtime. The calling code will receive unexpected object